# How can I make my GridView Border clickable in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have started learning flutter couple of days back.
I have a requirement to change border color when user clicked on that border, as I shown in the image below, border should turn red when used clicked on that part of border. How can I customize border such a way that I can make it clickable?

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      flex: 3,
      child: GridView.builder(
          itemCount: 9,
          gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 3,
          ),
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                _tapped(index);
              },
              child: Container(
                decoration:
                BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey, width: 5)),

              ),
            );
          }),
    );
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your entire grid in GestureDetector widget. Then in `onTapDown`, get the coordinates of a touch. Check if these coordinates correspond to any border.

Note that touching a line on a screen is not easy, even if your app is designed only for people with small fingers. So you may need to give them a little wider touch area than the width of a line on a screen.

Comment: Using this method there are high chances of error. Isn't it possible to create some custom border widget and there we can add listner? Such thing is very easier in wpf,  don't know why it is not there in flutter

Comment: Where do you see a chance for error? x between 0 and 10 is your left border, if you want to give it 10 pixels for touch, and so on. It's as precise as it gets. BTW, if something is doable, it does not mean it's the best way to do it. Having 24 individual widgets listening to touch events may not be as efficient as having 1. That being said, maybe your approach is better for some other reason, like not redrawing the entire grid. You know your requirements, so it's your decision.

Comment: Error as in I am worried if coordinate calculation goes wrong, as there will be devices of different size and grid also can have many cells 5x5 or 7x7

Comment: This is your grid. You know how many cells you have. If you have 4 x 4 grid, then your borders are at 0%, 25%, 50%, 75%, and 100% of its width and height. Device size makes no difference.